# Formatting text in botframwork Text property

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to return a string which have some new line characters in it like in the example below but it seems that it is not being treated correctly by the different clients. Is there anyway else I can add a new line into a simple Text response.

```
Here are few things I can help you with:\r\nFind a restaurants...
```

Answer (score 0):

BotFramework uses Markdown. To represent a paragraph break you need to have a blank line (i.e. "\n\n")

Markdown like this:

```
This is
paragraph one

This is 
paragraph two
```

Will be rendered as

```
This is paragraph one
This is paragraph two
```

See documentation at: http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/activities.html